# Getting the value of 'foo' for the closest previous row with higher 'bar'

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g-r2

From this initial data:

```sql
select level as foo, mod(ora_hash(level),4) as bar from dual connect by level<9;
/*
FOO                    BAR                   
---------------------- ----------------------
1                      3                     
2                      2                     
3                      3                     
4                      3                     
5                      2                     
6                      0                     
7                      3                     
8                      2                      
*/
```

I want to get the value of `foo, bar, prev_foo` for each row, where `prev_foo` is the value of `foo` from the closest 'previous' row (defined by ordering on `foo` which is unique) such that `bar` in that row is greater than `bar` in the current row. In other words, I want this result:

```sql
/*
FOO                    BAR                    PREV_FOO                 
---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1                      3                                           
2                      2                      1                   
3                      3                                          
4                      3                                           
5                      2                      4                     
6                      0                      5                    
7                      3                                           
8                      2                      7                     
*/
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is the range of possible values for `bar` always known prior to executing the statement or is it dependant on the statement? Your initial data suggests it's always `in (0,1,2,3)`.

Comment: It varies - the example is much simplified from my real world problem :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
with data as (
   select level as foo, mod(ora_hash(level),4) as bar from dual connect by level<9
)
select
  foo,
  bar,
  prev_foo
from
  data
model 
      dimension by (foo, bar)
      measures     (cast (null as number) as prev_foo,
                    cast (null as number) as store_foo
                   )
      rules        (
        store_foo[any, any] = cv(foo),
        prev_foo [any, any] = max(store_foo) [foo < cv(foo), bar > cv(bar)]
      );
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way, not using analytics so pretty inefficient:

```sql
with w as (select level as foo, mod(ora_hash(level),4) as bar from dual connect by level<9)
select foo, bar, (select max(foo) from w where foo<ww.foo and bar>ww.bar) from w ww;
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
with W as 
(select level as foo, mod(ora_hash(level),4) as bar 
   from dual 
connect by level<9)
select foo, bar, 
       case when prev_bar > bar then prev_foo else null end as prev_bar
  from (select foo, bar, 
               lag(foo) over (order by foo) as prev_foo,
               lag(bar) over (order by foo) as prev_bar
          from w)
 order by foo;
```

The with clause is the original query.

The inner most select uses analytics to get the previous (lag) value of foo and bar.

The outer query uses a case statement to implement your business rule.

Comment: This doesn't take account of cases where `prev_foo` is further back than 1 step - compare your results with mine or René's after increasing the size of the test data (eg `connect by level<15`)

Comment: I didn't test it, and in none of the test data has `prev_foo` further back than one step.

Comment: Yes, that's my bad, sorry. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer that works for nine rows, but not for more.  I'm posting it in case it sparks an idea.

```
WITH w AS (SELECT level as foo, mod(ora_hash(level),4) as bar FROM dual CONNECT BY Level<9)
SELECT foo, bar, Case When Highest > Bar Then 
   MAX(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY Highest 
     ORDER BY foo RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) 
   Else NULL End prev_foo
FROM 
   (SELECT foo, bar, max(bar) OVER (
      ORDER BY foo RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) Highest FROM w)
ORDER BY foo;
```

Comment: It was fun to take a crack at.